# Changing values in a nested JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've got a JSON object like this

```
var test = {
    "value1": "",
    "array1": {
       "value2": 0,
       "value3": 0
    }
}
```

Now I want to Iterate over array1 in the test JSON and multiply the values and store them again ...

I tried it this way but it doesn't store it

```
jQuery.each(test.array1, function (i, val) {
    test.array1.i = val * 1.3;
});
```

The multiplication works fine .. But how to restore it properly?

Comment: This is an Object literal, not an array

Comment: how should it looks like that it works like I expected ?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Could you post your expected output?

Comment: You really don't even need `val` at all, you can just use `*=`. Also, a plain old `for..in` loop is [even better](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36264014/5743988).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `test.array1[i]` instead of `test.array1.i`like following.

```
jQuery.each(test.array1, function (i, val) {
    test.array1[i] = val * 1.3;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) on keys array which are get by using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

```
Object.keys(test.array1).forEach(function(key) {
    test.array1[key] *= 1.3;
});
```

Using [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
Object.keys(test.array1).forEach(key => test.array1[key] *= 1.3);
```

```js
var test = {
    "value1": "",
    "array1": {
        "value2": 10,
        "value3": 30
    }
};

Object.keys(test.array1).forEach(function(key) {
    test.array1[key] *= 1.3;
});

console.log(test);
```

Comment: Wow, a plain javascript solution that's just as concise as jQuery

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

```js
var test = {
    "value1": "",
    "array1": {
       "value2": 1,
       "value3": 0
    }
}
jQuery.each(test.array1, function (i, val) {
                    console.log(i, val)
                    test.array1[i] = val * 1.3;//instead of test.array1.i = val * 1.3; use the bracket notation
                });

console.log(test)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Without jQuery it can be done like this:

```js
var test = {
  "value1": "",
  "array1": {
    "value2": 1,
    "value3": 2
  }
}

for (key in test.array1) {
  test.array1[key] *= 1.3;
}

console.log(test);
```

Run the snippet to check how it works.